# In Android, How to fold and unfold layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want use it as recyclerview's item.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**Question:**
What i want is that when i clicked red part, and then yellow part (which is folded before click) will be opened.

Is there any good way of doing this? Please give me teaching.

**Here is my post_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tv_like_count"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:minHeight="100dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_post_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffee58"
        android:minHeight="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ever heard of ExpandableListViews?

Comment: @Rotwang, I heard, but is that appropriate for this? Because i have low understanding of ExapndableListViews, i thought that is for something like list. How can i apply ExpandableListViews? Would you let me get some hint?

Comment: It's appropriate if you have a list of elements. If you have only a couple of rows... then you should really go the easy way: play with the height of the clicked row.